# What terminal does my Delta flight from BOS to BNA depart from?

Tags: delta-air-lines

I am flying out of Boston Logan airport Tuesday morning. What terminal Does Delta Connection fly out of going from Boston to Nashville Intl. Airport? The aircraft is an Embraer E-170.

Comment: Did you check the official airport website, http://www.massport.com/logan-airport/flights/airlines/ ?  It says Delta domestic departures are Terminal A.  Any reason to doubt it?

Answer (score 2):

Terminal A

Delta uses exclusively Terminal A in Boston (unless it's an international arrival which go through immigration and customs at Terminal E)

Answer (score 1):

Searching the flight number on Google will typically indicate the departure terminal, e.g. for [Qatar Airways QR 738](https://www.google.com/search?q=QR738), which departs from SFO airport:

[image]

Otherwise the departure airport will very likely have the information as well. https://flightaware.com/live/flight/QTR738 is another source.